# Fazer ordenação por Reflection com GetProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, classificação, reflexão

Tenho uma classe genérica com um método que precisa ordenar um objeto genérico.

Porém, dar erro dizendo que não reconhece o método Reflection GetProperty, pois lambda não consegue traduzir.

Como posso fazer essa lógica de ordenação genérica?

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    var obj = _repository.GetAll()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(TEntity).Name + "Id"));

    return obj.Pagination();
}
```

Segue a imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**---- Edit ----**

Refatorando (rsrs) o meu problema de forma resumida é que eu quero que um Serviço, seja qual for, quando quiser fazer uma consulta, mesmo que não passe nenhum parâmetro, o programa já limitar com paginação, boas práticas me entendem né! Abaixo alguns pontos para entenderem e no final coloquei o link do pastebin para visualizarem as classes ExtensionsQueries.cs, Service.cs e ClienteService.cs. Coloquei apenas parte das classes, espero que seja suficiente.

- Tenho uma classe genérica para meus Serviços herdarem onde contém os métodos comuns a todos os Serviços, como `GetAll(), GetBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter), Insert(TEntity obj)`, etc...;
- TEntity é uma Entidade Mapeada do Banco de Dados genérica que esta classe Service irá usar;

Até aqui está tudo funcionando perfeito, agora comecei a implementar uma forma de paginação que seja genérica tbm, então comecei a modificar algumas classes para adptar e foi aí que tive esse problema, comecei a fazer o seguinte:

- Criei um Extension Method de IQuerable para fazer Paginação do retorno de uma consulta;
- O problema é que o Skip só funciona se houver uma Ordenação antes;
- Já que vou ter que implementar uma Ordenação, estou querendo parametrizar o GetAll() e os demais que precisarão e receber algum atributo para ser usado na ordenação, tipo GetAll(obj paramsToOrder), mas se não passar (não será obrigatório) ordenar pela ChavePrimaria, que no meu caso é o Nome da Classe com o Id no final (que foi onde comecei a implementar como viram no exemplo que postei);
- Nem sei ainda como passar esses parâmetros, pois a idéia é passar N atributos para ordenar e cada um ter seu tipo de ordenação ASC ou DESC. Só que antes de chegar nessa parte já tive esse problema. T_T

Link: https://pastebin.com/ZiyjiurL

Comment: Qual a razão da necessidade de usar *reflection*? Por que não usar `OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)`?

Comment: @ramaral Sempre tem uma moda nos abusos. Embora ainda seja a exceção o maior abuso, reflexão está se tornando forte agora. Parece que está virando moda usar reflexão por usar, sem nenhuma necessidade e benefício. A reflexão com um literal sempre é um "erro", ela só é útil quando não se sabe o que deseja usar. Outro dia dei uma resposta sobre isso e deu uma confusão, porque quando a pessoa decide que vai usar o mecanismo, ninguém tira da cabeça :) Espero que neste caso seja diferente. Como L2E usa reflexão fica bem complicado funcionar reflexão em cima de reflexão.

Comment: Se fosse o caso de ser útil usar, se não soubesse mesmo o nome do campo, teria que fazer a reflexão fora para pegar o nome e aí usar isto na *query*. Ou então usar SQL mesmo :)

Comment: @bigown a minha questão surge exactamente por esse facto: ser conhecido não só o tipo como o nome do campo. Já agora, me passe o link da resposta que refere.

Comment: possivelmente você chamou esse método, informando o `TEntity` como uma `string`, aí ele tentou chamar `GetProperty(typeof(string))`. Posta a declaração da classe onde está esse método também

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou fazer assim?

_repository.GetAll().OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(x, null).ToString())).ToList();

Aqui ele ordena os objetos pelo Id de forma decrescente. Caso quiser crescente alterar para OrderBy